Pinescript: Add 20 week EMA to Daily chart
I typically look at the Daily chart, and already plot some EMAs as follows:
plot(ta.ema(close, 10), color = color.new(color.blue, 60))
plot(ta.ema(close, 20), color = color.new(color.green, 60))
plot(ta.ema(close, 50), color = color.new(color.yellow, 60))
plot(ta.ema(close, 200), color = color.new(color.red, 60))

How can I add the 20-Week EMA to these? I'm happy with hard-coded values like the above, but not sure how to achieve adding in the weekly

You use the security() function to get data from other timeframes. Here is the manual.
ema_20w = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "20W", ta.ema(close, 10))

